# How to remove call back when application goes to background?

Tags: android

I use runnable method they work properly when application goes background and app goes foreground they work but first time without background they cant work. work.
My code is below.

```
 runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WSSD.class);
                            toEdit.putString("LoginFlag", "true");
                            toEdit.commit();
                            intent.putExtra("AppMode", "online");
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.pull_out_left);

                            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                        }
                    };
```

/////////////////////////

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        MyApplication.activityResumed();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        MyApplication.activityPaused();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: There is no problem description. Nor any question. Please dont just dump code.

Comment: when we use this code that time intent to much time to call another activity.but app goes to background and resume that app then work well.

Comment: Sorry dont understand a word of this. Where is this all about? What should your code do?

Comment: You post a runnable for 'Login Success'. So all I have to do is wait 5s? no credentials? sounds legit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if(handler != null){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

> void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)
>
> Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.